# Displaying Partial View in a View and Passing Arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display two partial views in my index view. In those partial views are data grids that I want to display data when something is searched in the search box I have set up. Both of these pages work when I do them separately, but I don't know how do use them as partial views.

My View looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST"))
{
<div class="searchField">
    <div class="searchbox">
        Search: <input type="text" name="heatSearch" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
}

 <div>
 @Html.Partial("PartialChemAnalysis", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
 </div>
 @Html.Partial("PartialSlag", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string heatSearch)
    {
        ViewBag.SearchKey = heatSearch;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PartialChemAnalysis(string heatSearch)
    {
        HomeModel C = new HomeModel();
        IEnumerable<HomeModel> model = C.ChemList;
        C.ChemistryDataPull(heatSearch);

        return PartialView(C.ChemList);
    }

    public ActionResult PartialSlagView(string heatSearch)
    {
        PartialSlagViewModel D = new PartialSlagViewModel();
        IEnumerable<PartialSlagViewModel> model = D.SlagList;
        D.SlagViewDataPull(heatSearch); 

        return PartialView(D.SlagList);
    }
```

Ideally what's in that search box would be passed to both views and the grids would form based on that. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change my partial view calls in my view to:

```
@if(ViewBag.SearchKey != null)
{
 <div>
 @Html.Action("PartialChemAnalysis", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
 </div>
 <div>
 @Html.Action("PartialSlagView", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
</div>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this:

```
@{
      //create your first model
      HomeModel CModel = new HomeModel();
      CModel.ChemistryDataPull(Model.SearchValue);

      //create your other model
      PartialSlagViewModel DModel = new PartialSlagViewModel();
      DModel.SlagViewDataPull(Model.SearchValue); 
}

@Html.Partial("PartialAnalysis", CModel)
@Html.Partial("PartialSlag", DModel)
```

This is assuming you've already searched, processed a postback, and you've returned the SearchValue back to your view in your model. You could return it in ViewBag.SearchValue instead I suppose and replace `Model.SearchValue` with `ViewBag.SearchValue`, but your model would be a better place to store it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Nothing is being searched when the page loads. A user needs to enter a search and hit the button before that happens. My idea is to have the datagrids render on the same page after the search is performed.

Comment: You'll need to do it differently then. @Html.Partial() will happen when the page is loaded. What you're asking for is calling these method using AJAX and then dynamically rendering the results. You can certainly do that and it shouldn't be too difficult. I don't really have time to provide that solution, so I'll delete this answer in a few minutes. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I post it to another method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST"))
{
<div class="searchField">
    <div class="searchbox">
        Search: <input type="text" name="Search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
}


 @Html.Partial("PartialAnalysis", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
 @Html.Partial("PartialSlag", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)


//In Home Controller

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Search)
{
    ViewBag.SearchKey = Search;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Does putting the [HttpPost] above index change anything? When I did the changes you suggested and tried to run it I get a 404 error.

Comment: That means you don't have a PostController with a Home action.

Comment: @MikeC. But I have a HomeController with an Index action. Shouldn't that work? I'm pretty new to a lot of this, so forgive me if this sounds dumb.

Comment: Sorry what is in this post is correct and it is expecting a HomeController iwth an Index Action. You are correct.

Comment: @MikeC. I changed mine to his and it started doing that. I'll update my question to show that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Partial views do not require a controller action. The presence of a controller action will actually make it into a view.

In your @Html.Partial call you want to pass a view model for the view to consume. This is where you'd want to put the data for your grid, searched by whatever keywords, sorted, prepped and ready to render.

This can either be an entirely different view model you've created that is dedicated to supporting your partial view, exposed as a property in the parent page's view model, or simply an IEnumerable property in the parent page's view model that has the data (I prefer the first approach btw; it's heavier code-wise but preserves encapsulation better).

To wrap it all up, your controller looks like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string search)
    {
        return View(new IndexViewModel(search));
    }
}
```

Your view model looks like:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
private string _search;

public IndexViewModel(string search)
{
    _search = search;
}

public AnalysisViewModel AnalysisViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return new AnalysisViewModel(_search);
    }
}

public SlagViewModel SlagViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return new SlagViewModel(_search);
    }
}
```

}

and your view for showing the partials looks like

```
@Html.Partial("PartialAnalysis", Model.AnalysisViewModel)
@Html.Partial("PartialSlag", Model.SlagViewModel)
```

Comment: I've never used view models before, so just for clarification: How does the view model relate back to the models that have the methods? Or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: A view model is simply a class by another name, so it will have all the same properties & methods any other class has. 

However, given that the reason a VM exists is to contain all of the information needed for a view to render itself, you should be careful to never add anything to a VM that does not directly support the View its for.